# arangodb lock file issue

Tags: database, graph-databases, arangodb

So I downloaded ArangoDB via homebrew yesterday. The documentation said to use the following to get the server started:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/arangodb/<VERSION>/sbin/arangod &
```

I ended up using the prompt shown on the terminal

```
/usr/local/opt/arangodb/sbin/arangod
```

Don't know if that necessarily makes a difference. Nonetheless, I got the server working.

Then I wanted to set up authentication. The docs did not say how to stop a server. Since I didn't know how to, I just closed the terminal window

Then I ran

```
/usr/local/opt/arangodb/sbin/arango-secure-installation
```

This then gave me an error

```
FATAL [...] database is locked by process ..: please stop it first and check that the lockfile 'usr/local/var/lib/arangodb3/LOCK' goes away. If you are sure no other arangod process is running, please remove the lockfile '/usr/local/var/lib/arangodb3/LOCK' and try again
```

How do I fix this? I had the webgui running but closing that didn't make a difference.

Another stack overflow question said to use the following commands:

```
brew services stop arangod
brew services start arangod
brew services restart arangod
```

None of those worked?

So, two questions:

a) how do I solve this problem

b) and, in the future, how do I properly terminate a server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "brew services start/stop/restart arangod". It is no longer necessary to start arangod explicitly. If it has been started explicitly just do a "killall arangod" to stop it gracefully and start it using "brew services start".

Comment: Just for anyone else looking off of this  - I think it has to be ```brew services start arangodb``` and not ```brew services start arangod```. ```arangod``` was giving me an error

Comment: Finally got it working, thanks for the help - was stuck on it for a bit